# GeocodeQuery is not searching with current location

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I want to search a nearby hotel using 'searchTerm'. But GeocodeQuery is giving far away results even if I set 'MyGeocodeQuery.GeoCoordinate' with my current location. ( I have checked my current location co-ordinates by debugging which are accurate) I am not able to figure out what went wrong.

Please help me..

```
  MyGeocodeQuery = new GeocodeQuery();
    MyGeocodeQuery.SearchTerm = searchTerm;

    MyGeocodeQuery.GeoCoordinate = MyCoordinate == null ? new GeoCoordinate(0, 0) : MyCoordinate;


    MyGeocodeQuery.QueryCompleted += GeocodeQuery_QueryCompleted;
    MyGeocodeQuery.QueryAsync();
```

Comment: Do you get better results when using the built-in maps app?

Comment: Yes. Using here maps app on wp8.1 device.